# Arduino Uno board with male header pins

Tags: arduino-uno

I am currently working on a project that would greatly benefit from an arduino uno board with male headers soldered on instead of the female connectors. My question is hence extremely simple, yet I was not able to find an answer myself. Are there uno formfactor boards out there, with male header pins. I have found versions without headers for other boards, but not for the uno. Since I have already designed and 3d printed an enclosure that fits the uno and want to lower the overall height this seems like the easiest way to achieve this.

Comment: Several of the cheap Chinese clones that I've bought on eBay have come without soldered headers. Exactly the same form-factor as the Uno. Usual caveats about clone boards apply!

Comment: Along with various low-cost boards, the Adafruit Metro 328 is offered without headers soldered.  They consider this board to be a derivative of the Uno R3, but it does use the FT231X which may required different drivers than an Uno's ATMega16u2.  Also the USB connector is different so you may need to adjust your housing slightly.  Kind of ironic that while soldering headers is an extra step even with their selective solder machine, they charge slightly more for the no-headers version, perhaps stocking (or even return?) costs dominate manufacturing ones.

Answer (score 2):

I often unsolder the female connectors to solder wires directly. I would simply unsolder then and solder male headers in their place.